# Why is the hamburger icon of bootstrap4 not displaying the menus for small screen sizes?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want the navbar collapse on small screens with the help of the hamburger icon. The hamburger icon get displayed on smaller screens but it doesn't display any menu items on clicking. I am working with bootstrap4.

```css
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.nav-link:hover{
    color:blue;
    background-color:blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="style/popper.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-brand">
              <img src="images/32692600.jpg" style="width: 30px;" class="rounded-circle" alt="logo">
          </div> 
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link rounded text-dark px-md-4" href="#">Home </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link rounded text-dark px-md-4" href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link rounded text-dark px-md-4" href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link rounded text-dark px-md-4" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link rounded text-dark px-md-4" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
           </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? Open up your Google Chrome or Firefox web inspector and make sure all the files are getting loaded and there are no browser errors. If there are errors, you need to paste them here

Comment: `popper.min.js` file should be added before `bootstrap.min.js`. So, switch their position in the **HTML** file and try again

Comment: I get these errors while inspecting on chrome. 
   DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///D:/Portfolio/style/bootstrap.min.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///D:/Portfolio/style/popper.min.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file:///D:/Portfolio/style/bootstrap.min.css.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: You're using the Bootstrap 3.4.1 JavaScript file. Try it with the 4.0.0 version (to match your CSS, although the latest version if 4.6.0 for Bootstrap 4).

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was indeed with the different versions of bootstrap files.